# Method of estimating DEFLATE's (zlib) current compressed size without flush

Tags: c, compression, zlib, deflate

I'm currently writing a program that takes in cachelines (64 bytes, but adjustable), and attempts to fit as many as possible into a 512 byte block (again adjustable).

The issue is that I need to be able to get at least a rough estimate of the current compressed size after each call to deflate without flushing.  Every byte is important for my purpose and flushing adds very significant overhead depending on the data especially given the small block size I am using.  I have tried various different implementations with Z_SYNC_FLUSH and Z_PARTIAL_FLUSH, but both add to much overhead to be consistently useful.

My current naive approach is to compress 9 cachelines (576 bytes) and check if it will fit in the 512 block, if so add another cacheline and recompress the entire buffer and so on.  If the first 9 cachelines can't fit into the 512 block its just stored uncompressed (raw not deflated).

As you can imagine this approach takes far to long, a 7gb file took nearly 3 hours to compress with this method.

I noticed that the z_stream struct has an internal state that I could expose, but I didn't find any apparent way to utilize this to get an estimate.  I assume this is because until a flush no compression actually takes place.

Is there anyway at all to get an estimated size of the compressed output before an actual flush?
If not, is there anything I can do to reduce the time overhead of my current approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [fitblk.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/fitblk.c) for one approach. It has an overhead of about a factor of three, since it does three compressions per block.

The basic idea is to first compress enough to overfill the desired block. Then decompress until you process the amount of compressed data that would fit in the desired block, and then compress only that. A second pass at that refines the fit.

Comment: I really appreciate this, it looks like I will be able to modify this a little to fit my needs perfectly.  Thanks again!